# Why does this attempt to customize a type constraint error message fail?

Tags: perl, moose

The following construct creates a type constraint that functions as expected (checks for the "Roles::Thing" role when an attribute is set)  When an attribute is rejected due to not passing the constraint I would expect the custom error message "Not a thing" to appear; however the default error message is still being given.  What am I doing wrong?

```
role_type 'DoesThing', {
   role => 'Roles::Thing',
   message => sub { "Not a thing." }
};
```

Update: I did not provide enough context in the original post.  The way I am trying to use the new type is:

```
has things => (
  isa => 'ArrayRef[DoesThing]'
);
```

The type validation does work as expected; however I still get the default error message.  My custom "Not a thing" error message is not propagated as I would have expected it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is what you get for an `ArrayRef` type, regardless of what you're expecting inside it.

To get a custom error message you'll need to incorporate `ArrayRef` into your type declaration:

```
subtype 'ArrayOfThings', 
    as 'ArrayRef[Roles::Thing]', 
    message { 'Not an array of things' };
```